# uncheck all checkboxes leaving disabled one using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using following approach to uncheck all checkboxes except disabled one

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){  
      if(!this.attr(':disabled')){
         this.checked = false; 
      } 
});
```

but not working

Comment: replace `this` with `$(this)` and `attr` with `is`: `if(!$(this).is(':disabled')){`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)/[not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) along with [:disabled](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selector

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:disabled)').prop('checked', false); 
//or
$('input[type=checkbox]').not(':disabled').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){  
      if(!$(this).prop('disabled')){
        $(this).prop("checked", false); 
      } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () { 
     var elem = $("#" + this.id); 
     if (!elem.attr("disabled")) { 
         this.checked = true; 
     } 
 });
```

Comment: Just a tip, a good answer usually comes with an explanation of how your solution solves the OP question.